# How to exit from linux sendmail on centos 6

Tags: linux, sendmail

I was looking up something here on stack overflow and the answer told me to enter

```
sendmail -bt
```

in the shell. I was able to do what the question said but now I'm unable to exit the sendmail program. `CTRL+c, CTRL+x, q, exit, bye, quit` does not seem to work. How do you exit the sendmail program once your in without terminating my ssh connection?

Comment: What about `/quit`? Also, you didn't mention trying `Ctrl-D` (which usually marks the end of the standard input stream).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

as raina77ow pointed out `/quit` or `CTRL+D` will terminate the program.